# Hidden div moves fixed div to middle of window

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I am pretty new to positioning in css (e.g. relative, fixed, absolute). What I'm trying to do is create a fixed nav bar at the top of my screen that remains there while the user scrolls down the content.

This is accomplished easily enough by positioning it as absolute, top:0, left:0. The problem is, I have a hidden contact panel that slides down when the user clicks 'contact' in the nav menu. I want the nav bar to be moved down with it, appearing below the contact panel. So I had to change the nav from position absolute to fixed. This allowed it to be moved down below the contact panel, but when you continue scrolling, the nav bar remains in the middle of the window, instead of at the very top.

I have some sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hwDwR/51/

So to sum up, I want the green nav bar to "stick" to the blue contact panel until the nav bar reaches the top of the window. I want the nav bar to always be displayed at the top (like it appears before showing the hidden div) even after displaying the hidden content.

Hopefully I have been able to explain what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**RESOLVED: Thanks again for the replies, but this is the effect I was aiming for: http://jsfiddle.net/hwDwR/66/ (will post as answer in 6 hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the effect I was after: http://jsfiddle.net/hwDwR/66/

Thanks again for your replies, I have been puzzled by this for a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please: http://jsfiddle.net/z2LVR/

Reason it was behaving was because the content div was residing on top of the fixed `div`

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
 <div id="nav">
     my | nav | bar | contact (click me)
 </div>
  <div class="panel">
  Contact information to slide down (and stay down).
 </div>




$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideDown("slow"); // you can use slideToggle if you want. Just a suggestion.
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I actually want the nav bar to be pushed down under the contact panel (as shown in my code). The problem is, once pushed down, when the user scrolls down, the div remains in the middle. This makes sense due to my code, I just don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: @Bob no worries man - you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z2LVR/3/ ? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to `click` handler:

`$("#nav").animate({'top':'200px'},'slow');`

and add `position: fixed` to the `.panel`

Comment: Thanks, this does the same as above, and is a useful alternative.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/hwDwR/57/

Wrapped the 'nav' and 'panel' in a div and applied the fixed positioning to it.

Comment: Thanks, but again, not quite what I was looking to do. Because it leaves the contact panel on the screen. It's close to what I want and could use it, but I thought of another solution.